# How to prove that something is or isn't a function of something else?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How do we prove that something is or isn't a function of some other thing?

For example,
Let 
$$Y_1 = 5$$
$$Y_2 = X^2$$
Clearly, $Y_1$ is not a function of $X$ whilst $Y_2$ is a function of $X$. How do we prove that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could say that there is a free instance of $X$ in $Y_2$. Would you want $Y_3=X-X\equiv 0$ to be a function of $X$ or not?

Comment: A constant function still counts as a function, so $Y_1$ qualifies also. However this remark maybe doesn't address the "semantic" of the phrase "is a function of", which maybe means as $X$ changes then $Y$ does also, at least sometimes.

Comment: Does that mean that we can consider anything to be a function of everything? Am I mixing functionality and dependency?